# jquery countdown polar clock not working in IE9 or 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, countdown

I'm using a jquery countdown timer and it works everywhere, even in IE7 but not in IE9 or IE8. I've been racking my brain and I can't figure out the problem. The divs that are supposed to rotate aren't, is my guess, but I don't understand why it would work in IE7 of all places but not IE9. If there is more than half the time left for the given unit of time it shows half of the green circle, if it's less than half it disappears an only leaves the gray background.

You can see the test page here: http://tiffanyisrael.com/construction/

I also set up a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cx2ut/1/

Any help or suggetions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have a rotate function at the end of your scripts in which you do some calculations to rotate when it's IE, why don't you use http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/ to handle IE as well?

Comment: It sounds like a great idea but I think this is a little beyond me. I gave it a try and came up with this... 
`var spin = function (){
   $($this).rotate({
      angle:''+angle+''
      }
  );
   };`

and changing this...
`else if(element.css("filter")!==undefined)
element.css('filter',spin);`

It didn't work though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out IE9, now I have to figure out IE8 :(

`else if(element.css('ms-transform')!==undefined)
            element.css('ms-transform',rotate);`

This looks for ms-transform in the element and adds it with the rotate angle, ms-transform is how IE9 rotates elements

Here's the update jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cx2ut/3/

An IE8 fix coming soon hopefully!